# how can i reference the instance of an object?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Here's the thing i create a new instance of a class in a file then i'm trying to reference that specific instance in another file.

This is the initilization of the object in RegistroUI.

```js
CuentaBancaria Cuenta = new CuentaBancaria(nombre);
```

This is my code trying to reference that same class in IngresoUI.

```js
textBienvenido.setText("BIENVENID@ USUARIO" + Cuenta.getNombre());
```

All of this is in the same package and written in java.
Please any idea will help :D

I can't create another object because it won't have the same values for attributes and i don't need to import because is already in the same package.

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) - you might also want to do some research into dependency injection ... and just to head it off, `static` is NOT the solution you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference an instance of an object, you need to pass it somehow into IngresoUI. For example via injection in constructor of IngresoUI.

```
CuentaBancaria cuenta;
IngresoUI(CuentaBancaria cuenta){
    this.cuenta=cuenta
}
```

Another method is to inject IngresoUI into RegistroUI and then pass CuentaBancaria cuenta into some method of IngresoUI.

```
IngresoUI ingresoUI;
RegistroUI( IngresoUI ingresoUI){
    this.ingresoUI = ingresoUI;
}
void someMethodOfRegistroUI(){ //Method where you create CuentaBancaria 
    int nobre = 10;
    CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria(nombre);
    ingresoUI.someMethodOfIngresoUI(cuenta);//call a method of IngresoUI
    //where you need CuentaBancaria cuenta;
}
```